# Is there a way 2 jobs can communicate on hashicorp's nomad

Tags: consul, hashicorp, nomad

I have 2 jobs:-

an api with websocket
a service that sends message to the websocket of service 1
Is there a way service 2 can send message to service 1’s endpoint?

Note:-
Service 1 is a public api, but i dont want to expose the websocket to the internet

I already have them communicating via the public internet, but want the websocket to be private.

Answer (score 0):

In the job service 1 you should register the service block either in Nomad or Consul provider. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/service .

Then service 2 should generate a template using the registered services matching service 1. Then this template should be used for service 2 configuration. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/template#consul-services  and https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/template#nomad-services for an example.